# How do I make an animation look the same on all devices?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app and want an animation by clicking a button that raises a text area so people can read the part that is hidden. I was able to do it using the following code:

```
ivFundo.animate().translationY(-550).start();
```

On my Samsung J5 (Android 6.0) it looks the way I want, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

But when I tested on my brother's cell phone, a Samsung J2 (Android 6.0), the text goes up a lot more than it should. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: What kind of view is ivFundo?

Comment: @pantos27 Actually, I'm using an animate() for each screen object, so it pushes all up at the same time.

Comment: Why not use a scroll view and set the scroll when needed?

Comment: @pantos27 It's because in fact, with animation it gets a lot more beautiful aesthetically.